# I'm trying to create a program that reads a string and displays how many of each letter there is, but it isn't working

Tags: java, loops, char

```
import java.util.*;
public class Practice_7_4
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int counter = 0;
      String statement;
      int length;
      char space = ' ';
      String word = "";
      char letter;
      char check;
      int count = 0;
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
      statement = input.nextLine();
      length = statement.length();
      System.out.print("Entered String: " + statement);
      while(counter <= length-1)
      {
         letter = statement.charAt(counter);
         for(int charcount = 0; charcount <= length-1; charcount++)
         {
            check = statement.charAt(charcount);
            if(letter != ' ' && charcount < length-1)
            {
               if(Character.toLowerCase(letter) == Character.toLowerCase(check))
               {
                  count+=1;
               }  
            }  
         }
         if(letter != ' ')
            System.out.printf("\nletter %c:\t %d", letter, count);
         counter += 1 ;
         count = 0;
      }
   }
}

Output of "I am tired" in the program:
letter i:    2
letter a:    1
letter m:    1
letter t:    1
letter i:    2
letter r:    1
letter e:    1
letter d:    0
```

My problem is how can i delete the repeated letter 'i' from being printed twice and how can i get my code to count the last character instead of producing a 0? This is my only question but it says add more detail so i am going to type until i reach the minimum amount.

Comment: Why `... && charcount < length-1`?  That as much as says "`charcount` **is not the last position**"  So, of course, you never count the last character in `statement`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collection for this purpose.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int occurrence = 0;
    String arr="I am tired";
    List<Character> nos =new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++){
        nos.add(Character.toLowerCase(arr.charAt(i)));
    }
    Set<Character> uniqueNos = new HashSet<>(nos);
    for(char temp:uniqueNos) {
        for(char tempList:nos) {
            if(String.valueOf(temp).equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(tempList))) {
                occurrence++;
            }
        }
        if(temp!=' ')
        System.out.println(temp+ " Appears "+occurrence +" times");
        occurrence = 0;
    }
}
```

Here first we create a Arraylist of Character to  String. then store each character into list.

then create a hashset from list.hashset contains only unique data.

so then pick one char from hashset and compare with list all item if match then increment counter.

Answer (score 0):

The following program does the work.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Practice_7_4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int counter = 0;
    String statement;
    int length;
    char space = ' ';
    String word = "";
    char letter;
    char check;
    int count = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
    statement = input.nextLine();
    char c[] = statement.toCharArray();
    length = statement.length();
    System.out.print("Entered String: " + statement);
    while (counter <= length - 1) {
        letter = c[counter];
        for (int charcount = 0; charcount <= length - 1; charcount++) {
            check = c[charcount];
            if (letter != ' ' && charcount <= length - 1) {
                if (Character.toLowerCase(letter) == Character.toLowerCase(check)) {
                    //System.out.println(true);
                    count += 1;
                    c[charcount]=' ';
                }

            }
        }//System.out.println(Arrays.asList(c).toString());
        if (letter != ' ')
            System.out.printf("\nletter %c:\t %d", letter, count);
        counter += 1;
        count = 0;
    }
    System.out.println("hello"+statement);
}
}
```

Few changes which I made:

1. Made a character array of the string, to be able to replace already seen characters with space.
2. Replace the character being searched with space (' '), at every place found and increase the count thereby.